# Cannot see "Create Aurora read replica" on RDS Postgresql db instance - version 11.12

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I am using RDS Postgresql db instance - v11.12 (not Aurora) and I cannot see option "Create Aurora read replica" as expected. Any config I need to update?
I checked and see the region us-east-1 have that Aurora matching version with Postgres 11.12. But not sure why I cannot see replica option.
Appreciate any help :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This happened for me as well, I didn't see the obvious reason why I can't create an Aurora Read Replica, so I tried creating it via CLI and it worked:

To create cluster

```
aws rds create-db-cluster  
    --db-cluster-identifier <new cluster name> 
    --db-subnet-group-name <subnet: same as original db> 
    --vpc-security-group-ids <security group id: like sg-12345678> 
    --engine aurora-postgresql 
    --engine-version <same as original db> 
    --replication-source-identifier <arn of original db: like arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:065414729932:db:my-database> 
    <if encrypted>
    --storage-encrypted 
    --kms-key-id <kms key arn, like: arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:065514443312:key/195dff9f-0ee3-1024-b61f-3e19e4523495>
```

and instance in it

```
aws rds create-db-instance 
    --db-cluster-identifier <cluster name>
    --db-instance-class <desired instnace class>
    --db-instance-identifier <id of new instance>
    --engine aurora-postgresql
```

and you will get Aurora Read Replica cluster (which will be read-only unless you promote it)

[Commands are taken from official guide "Migrating data to Amazon Aurora"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Migrating.html#AuroraPostgreSQL.Migrating.RDSPostgreSQL.Replica)

Comment: In that case you might need to add the scaling config to the cluster: --serverless-v2-scaling-configuration "MinCapacity=8,MaxCapacity=64"

Comment: In case of a serverless target, use in create-db-instance:--db-instance-class "db.serverless"